# Topological genus and number of holes

Tags: general-topology, surfaces

I' having trouble understanding the topological genus works. It's been introduced to me via the Euler characteristic and then I've been told that, practically speaking, if the surface is orientable it counts the number of holes in it. Indeed I found another definition:

The genus of a connected, orientable surface is an integer representing the maximum number of cuttings along non-intersecting closed simple curves without rendering the resultant manifold disconnected (from Wikipedia).

But how is this connected to the genus definition via Euler characteristic?
And is genus an actually important property? The property in itself doesn't seem so relevant, also because two surfaces with the same genus can be very different (non homeomorphic).

Comment: About your last question: Two spaces with the same fundamental group of (co-)homology groups can also be non-homeomorphic, would you say these are not important concepts? It's the other way around: If two spaces have different genera, then they are not homeomorphic.

Comment: I don't know too much about them, but for instance we need a space to be contractible (all homology groups are null groups, if I recall correctly) for the Poincarè Lemma to hold true, so those properties have clear applications and consequences, while I don't really understand what the genus tells us.

Comment: Contractibility is not equivalent to trivial homology groups and contractibility is too strong anyway, the statement of the Poincarè Lemma is trivial in that case, you would instead be looking for star domains. And of course, these properties have consequences, they restrict the class of topological spaces - if you take spaces with certain trivial homology groups, then you are just looking at special spaces, which will satisfy certain properties that are not given in general. Similary, if you look at spaces with e.g. genus 0, you will be looking at special spaces.

Comment: As I also mentioned in my previous comment: If two spaces have different genera, then they are not homeomorphic (and such statements are among the main goals of topology). That is an extremely useful application if you think about it. You can also take a look at the classification of surfaces where the genus plays a key role.